# Android apk is not updating in Quasar using cordova

Tags: android, cordova, quasar

I'm using Quasar to develope an App and a website. When I build the android app via 'cordova build android' in the cordova folder I get a new .apk, but it's content is old. Which command am I missing to update the ressources of the apk. I tried 'cordova clean' or deleating the dist folder in the quasar project and doing 'quasar build' but it didn't help. Which files does cordova use and how are they getting updated? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out, you have to run 'quasar build -m cordova -T android' in the quasar-project-folder to overwrite the files in the cordova folder and then run 'cordova build android' (this one has to be done inside the cordova folder) to get the new apk. Maybe you'll have to delete your previous apk before building in cordova